# How to interact with other layers in a QGIS Python init function?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2

I am using QGis and making a Python script that sets the Python Init function to a custom UI file. I have a function with the following signature:

```
def formOpen(dialog, layer, feature):
    ...
```

I can access the given layer and it's contents - this works fine. But what should I do in order to access other layers?

My use case is the following: Whenever a given feature F of layer A is modified, I want to calculate the intersection of feature F with all geometry objects of layer B and show it to user. This information is later saved to the database.

I understand that in order to do that, I should be able to access the interface object. In my plugin I save the reference to the interface by:

```
self.iface = iface.
```

However, the Python init function is out of my plugin. Should I put it inside my plugin? Or use global variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QgsMapLayerRegistry`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html) is a singleton. You can therefore access it without iface.

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
```